# Get n-th element of an array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

As part of my document in MongoDB I'm storing an array of objects. How can I query it for only the 4th element of the array for example? So I don't want the get the entire array out, just the 4th element.

Comment: Or perhaps [Reaching Objects Array Element by Position](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29#DotNotation%28ReachingintoObjects%29-ArrayElementbyPosition)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use `$slice`.

```
db.foo.find({ bar : "xyz" } , { my_array : { $slice : [n , 1] } } )
```

will retrieve the nth element of the array "my_array" of all documents in the foo collection where bar = "xyz".

Some other examples from the MongoDB documentation:

```
db.posts.find({}, {comments:{$slice: 5}}) // first 5 comments
db.posts.find({}, {comments:{$slice: -5}}) // last 5 comments
db.posts.find({}, {comments:{$slice: [20, 10]}}) // skip 20, limit 10
db.posts.find({}, {comments:{$slice: [-20, 10]}}) // 20 from end, limit 10
```

Which you can read here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields

Comment: small correction to your line

" db.foo.find({ bar : "xyz" } , { my_array : { $slice : [n , 1] } } )
will retrieve the nth element of the array "my_array" of all documents in the foo collection where bar = "xyz". "



i think this will give the (n+1)th  element from the array my_array

because $slice : [n, 1]  , means skip n , limit 1 , so it will return the n+1 th element from the array

Answer (score 22):

You can use the [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) operator new in MongoDB 3.2 to return the element at the specified array index.

---

Demo:

A collection named *baskets* contains documents that look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("578f326f6db61a299a383c5a"),
    "fruits" : [
        "apple",
        "mango",
        "banana",
        "apricot",
        "cherry"
    ]
}
```

The following query return the element at index `-2` (second element)  in the "fruits" array.

```
db.baskets.aggregate(
    [
        { "$project": { "matched": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$fruits", 1 ] } } } 
    ] 
)
```

which produces

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("578f326f6db61a299a383c5a"), 
    "matched" : "mango" 
}
```

And the following query the element before the last element in the array; thus the element at index `-2`

```
db.baskets.aggregate(
    [
        { "$project": { "matched": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$fruits", -2 ] } } } 
    ] 
)
```

which yields:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("578f326f6db61a299a383c5a"), 
    "matched" : "apricot" 
}
```

Comment: For me, this is the Accepted Answer! I needed a way to swap between 2 elements in an array but couldn't find how to access an element by index upon an *update*. This $arrayElemAt operator saved me a ton.

Answer (score 9):

Another way to do this is to use the update array syntax. Here, `contribs.1` sets the second element in the `contribs` array to have value `ALGOL 58` (Taken from the [manual page on update syntax](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-arrays))

```
db.bios.update(
   { _id: 1 },
   { $set: { 'contribs.1': 'ALGOL 58' } }
)
```

Comment: But we are looking for `get` the element, not `push` the element :?

Comment: As the post makes no attempt to answer the original question and is not useful, **consider downvoting it** in order to give it a chance to be removed.