# php mongodb find nth entry in collection

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to retrieve the nth entry in my collection.
This seems to work using `find()` but i would think there is a cleaner solution using `findOne()` and maybe `sort()`? 
can anyone help out with a better way of writing this please

```
$mongo = new Mongo();
$db = $mongo->mydb;
$collection = $db->user;

$cursor = $collection->find();
$i=0;
foreach ($cursor as $obj){
    if ($i==3)
        echo $obj["_id"];//echo's the 3rd entry id
    $i++;
}
```

The [solution provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223273/get-n-th-element-of-an-array-in-mongo) is not applicable to my problem, which is why I'm asking this question.

Comment: similar question was answered here,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223273/get-n-th-element-of-an-array-in-mongo

Comment: @creminsn, that's about arrays in a document, t q is talking about the nth document in a collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use skip of (n-1), from your code above:

```
$cursor = $collection->find();
$cursor->skip(3);
$cursor->next();
$doc = $cursor->current();
```

But I think probably the best way is to keep a counter in your document that you can use as an index.

Comment: thank you, can you elaborate on why one would need an index? btw without the line `$cursor->next()`, no output

Comment: So that you can find uniquely that document with one action, rather than a cursor that might potentially have to "walk" through the entire collection (depending on the value of your skip)

Comment: so a counter like my original post? or something else?

Comment: find() selects a cursor to all documents in the collection, it would be better if you could go directly to your document with say, $collection->find(array('myIndex' => 3))

Comment: do you mean to change the schema so that in my collection there is a field called `myIndex`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am suggesting.

Answer (score 4):

Skip() does not use an index effectively so putting a index on any field within the collection would be pointless.

Since you wish to `skip()` nth documents, if the value of `skip()` is low (depends on your system but normally under 100K rows on a full collection scan) then it might be OK. The problem is that normally it is not. Mongo, even with an index, will be required to scan the entire result set before being able to skip over it which will induce a full collection scan no matter what in your query.

If you were to do this often and in random ways it might be better to use an incrementing ID combineing another collection with `findAndModify` to produce an accurate document number ( http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/How+to+Make+an+Auto+Incrementing+Field ).

This however induces problems, you must mantain this ID especially when deletes occur. One method around this is to mark documents as deleted instead of actually deleting them. When you query for the exact document you omit deletes and `limit()` by one allowing you to get the next closest document to that position like so:

```
$cur = $db->collection->find(array('ai_id' => array('$gt' => 403454), 'deleted' => 0))->limit(1);
$cursor->next();
$doc = $cursor->current();
```