# Project first item in an array to new field (MongoDB aggregation)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am using Mongoose aggregation (MongoDB version 3.2).

I have a field `users` which is an array. I want to `$project` first item in this array to a new field `user`.

I tried

```
  { $project: {
    user: '$users[0]',
    otherField: 1
  }},

  { $project: {
    user: '$users.0',
    otherField: 1
  }},

  { $project: {
    user: ｛ $first: '$users'},
    otherField: 1
  }},
```

But neither works.

How can I do it correctly? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get n-th element of an array in MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223273/get-n-th-element-of-an-array-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 186, accepted):

**Update:**

Starting from v4.4 there is a dedicated operator [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first-array-element/#mongodb-expression-exp.-first):

```
{ $project: {
    user: { $first: "$users" },
    otherField: 1
}},
```

It's a syntax sugar to the

**Original answer:**

You can use [arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/):

```
{ $project: {
    user: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$users", 0 ] },
    otherField: 1
}},
```

Comment: how can we directly project array element's key? like.. [{ name: 'foo' }] , I want to project name directly.

Comment: @SachinBhandari { $arrayElemAt: [ "$users.key.anotherNestedKey", 0 ] }

Comment: It is returning one element - but still returning an array :(

Comment: @Saw https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first-array-element/#behavior says it should be the item itself.

Comment: Had to do user: { $first: { $first: "$users" } } - although I didn't have array of arrays

Answer (score 21):

If it is an array of objects and you want to use just single object field, ie:

```
{
 "users": [
    {name: "John", surname: "Smith"},
    {name: "Elon", surname: "Gates"}
   ]
}
```

you can use:

```
{ $project: { user: { $first: "$users.name" } }
```

**Edit** (exclude case  - after comment from @haytham)

In order to exclude a single field from a nested document in array you have to do 2 projections:

```
 { $project: { user: { $first: "$users" } }
```

Which return whole first object, and then exclude field you do not want, ie:

```
{ $project: { "user.name" : 0 }
```

Comment: how can we exclude the match? I mean how to pass the 0 after that?
 { $project: {
    user: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$users", 0 ] },
    otherField: 1
}}, or { $project: { user: { $first: "$users.name" } }

Comment: @haytham - added example to the answer. I think this cannot be done in a single projection ($first + exclude field from the result of first).

Answer (score 11):

Starting `Mongo 4.4`, the aggregation operator [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/first-array-element/) can be used to access the first element of an array:

```
// { "users": ["Jean", "Paul", "Jack"] }
// { "users": ["Claude"] }
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $project: { user: { $first: "$users" } } }
])
// { "user" : "Jean" }
// { "user" : "Claude" }
```