# Aggregate data to group by first value of an array

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

Assume there is the following data in my db and I want to aggregate some data grouped by the first target score value.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7f6a937563a63c1d8b4639"),
    "target" : [
        {
            "score" : 3
        },
    {
            "score" : 2
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7f6a937563a63c1d8b4640"),
    "target" : [
        {
            "score" : 1
        },
    {
            "score" : 4
        }
    ]
}
```

So I'm trying to do this:

```
data.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $match: { 'target.0.score': { $exists: true } }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$target.0.score',
        Datasets: { $sum: 1 }
      }
    }
  ]
)
```

*In my code I'm doing some average calculation, that's why I'm using the aggregate method*

The result of the query is

```
[ { _id: [], Datasets: 2 } ]
```

But I would expect

```
[
  { _id: 3, Datasets: 1 },
  { _id: 1, Datasets: 1 }
]
```

`_id` should be the grouped score value with the count of all datasets of this score (and some average calculation for this group)

Comment: It's a find/match syntax to access elements in array. For $group you need to use $arrayElemAt. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39196537/project-first-item-in-an-array-to-new-field-mongodb-aggregation

Comment: @AlexBlex But `$arrayElemAt: ['$target', 0]` gives me the object. I need to get the score value.

Comment: ~just use $let, see my answer~ see Lucas' answer

Comment: @AlexBlex Why did you delete your answer. It was working. Lucas' answer does not consider the `score` field.

Comment: Fair enough. I undeleted mine to show an alternative approach and corrected Lucas'  one to use `score`. The extra stage is better in this particular case. $addFields instead of $project might be a bit more flexible tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to group by first target score, first you need to `project` the first target score, then group by it:

```
data.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $match: { 'target.0.score': { $exists: true } }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        first_target_score: {
          $arrayElemAt: [
            '$target', 0
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$first_target_score.score',
        Datasets: { $sum: 1 }
      }
    }
  ]
)
```

I'm pretty sure this will work, but I don't have the means to test it out now, just give it a try

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it was already answered, but anyway:

```
data.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $match: { 'target.0.score': { $exists: true } }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {$let:{
            vars: {t0: {$arrayElemAt:["$target", 0]}},
            in: "$$t0.score"
        }},
        Datasets: { $sum: 1 }
      }
    }
  ]
)
```